# Sklearn RANSAC without intercept

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am trying to fit a linear model without intercept (forcing the intercept to 0) using sklearn's [RANSAC: RANdom SAmple Consensus](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/linear_model.html#ransac-regression) algorithm. In [LinearRegression](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression) one can easily set `fit_intercept=False`. However, this option does not seem to exist in RANSAC's [list of possible parameters](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RANSACRegressor.html). Is this functionality not implemented? How should one do it? What are alternatives to sklearn's RANSAC to objectively select inliers and outliers, that allow setting the intercept to 0?

The implementation should look like this, but it raises an error:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RANSACRegressor

ransac_regressor = RANSACRegressor(fit_intercept=False)
```

Comment: It would be nice if the person who voted down could explain why. There is a multitutde of questions on sklearn's RANSAC on this website, normally well received.

Comment: I guess the downvoter voted since this question is more about the implementation of the linear models than about coding, thus stats.stackexchange would be a better place to ask. This is also the reason why I voted to close this question. Furthermore many just like to see a few lines of code showing where you stumbled upon the problem.

Comment: I see, thanks (also for the answer!). I had originally asked this question on stats.stackexchange, but I realized it is not about the RANSAC algorithm or theory itself. The question us about how to properly do the coding to use the python package. Moreover,  [their documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/faq.html#what-s-the-best-way-to-get-help-on-scikit-learn-usage) suggests we come here "for scikit-learn usage questions". Thanks again!

Comment: You are welcome! Yeah, it's one of these borderline cases, where you need to have some knowledge about the statistics part **and** the coding part. But in my experience, you'll get the best answers for these cases on the specific stackexchange communities like stats.stackexchange. Unluckily the SO community is very unwelcoming und absolutely unflexible towards questions which **do not fit their standards *exactly*** and thus downvotes are very frequent in these borderline cases.

Comment: I added a very simple code snippet to your question. Like this, at least the "we want to see some code"-part of SO will be satisfied. ;) Furthermore I upvoted you question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`RANSAC` is a wrapper around other linear regressors to implement them using random sampling consesus, thus you can simply set the `base_estimator` to `fit_intercept=False`:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RANSACRegressor, LinearRegression

ransac_lm = RANSACRegressor(base_estimator=LinearRegression(fit_intercept=False))
```